# How git hooks can get parameters via command-line arguments and stdin?

Tags: git, husky

I want to get value using parameters and use them in pre-push in hooks. How to to get? And also how to set environmental variables for HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS and HUSKY_GIT_STDIN?

Below is my .huskyrc file:

```
{
 "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "Pre-push": "echo HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS run test" 
}
}
```

Comment: if this is related to [tag:husky], consider adding it

Comment: I already have huskyrc file with hooks configuration. 
I have edited the question please check.

Comment: Yes, Understood :)

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not .